# Does LinkedIn Share API support escaped fragment URL's (hasbang url)

Tags: angularjs, escaping, linkedin-api, social-networking

Using the customized URL method is it possible to share a URL that implements the Escaped Fragment protocol?

For example a url in the following format:

```
https://www.example.com/#!/my-angularjs-page
```

So far from my experience, LinkedIn always removes the hashtag thus only retaining the domain name part of the URL:

```
https://www.example.com/
```

And therefore only the homepage is being shared.

References:

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin

Answer (score 0):

As of March 2016 the answer is no, LinkedIn share API customised URL method doesn't support hashbang URL's.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the characters, whenever you want to use `#`, `&`, `?`, and a few other reserved characters as the value of a `GET` parameter in a URL.  It's called [URL-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).  The standard LinkedIn format is...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

So, for your site, notice how I am doing the encoding of these special characters...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F%23!%2Fmy-angularjs-page
```

`#` becomes `%23`.  Afterall, how is the browser supposed to know that `#` there is for the URL you are sharing, or for the LinkedIn page itself?  It needs to be able to distinguish, and it does that with encoding.

More Info: **[Official LinkedIn Share Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**